# How to convert new Canvas ui image position to linerenderer position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an image UI in a canvas with Screen Space - Camera render mode. What I like to do is move my `LineRenderer` to the image vertical position by looping through all the `LineRenderer` positions and changing its y axis. My problem is I cant get the correct position of the image that the `LineRenderer` can understand. I've tried using `ViewportToWorldPoint` and `ScreenToWorldPoint` but its not the same position.

```
    Vector3 val = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(image.transform.position.x, image.transform.position.y, Camera.main.nearClipPlane));

    for (int i = 0; i < newListOfPoints.Count; i++)
    {
        line.SetPosition(i, new Vector3(newListOfPoints[i].x, val.y, newListOfPoints[i].z));
    }
```

Screenshot result using `Vector3 val = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(image.transform.localPosition.x, image.transform.localPosition.y, -10));`

The green `LineRenderer` is the result of changing the y position. It should be at the bottom of the square image.
[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of how your current code renders? Matching things up between screenspace and worldspace are tricky things to do and it helps to see what's going on.

Comment: How about printing out the screen space position of your image? Maybe it is not at the position that you think it should be. Another thing to try could be to see what the (0, 0) or (100, 100) is transformed into.

Comment: @YAC The real problem is that overlay canvas objects use an entirely different coordinate system from worldspace...and viewport space.

Comment: @unice, if your problem is solved, please accept the answer so that it will  be useful to others.

Comment: @Programmer, sorry for the late reply. Been testing the script and it works perfectly in Canvas with render mode Screen Space - Overlay. But when I use Screen Space - Camera and drag my main camera to the render camera, the linerenderer's position is different. But this is enough to answer my question, I will stick to overlay for now. Thanks Draco18s   for the time and effort to answer my question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, this was annoying and complicated.

Here's the code I ended up with. The code in your question is the bottom half of the `Update()` function. The only thing I changed is what was passed into the `ScreenToWorldPoint()` method.  That value is calculated in the upper half of the `Update()` function.

The `RectTransformToScreenSpace()` function was adapted from [this Unity Answer](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1013011/convert-recttransform-rect-to-screen-space.html) post<sup>1</sup> about getting the screen space coordinates of a `RectTransform` (which is exactly what we want in order to convert from screen space coordinates back into world space!) The only difference is that I was getting inverse Y values, so I changed from `Screen.height - transform.position.y` to just `transform.position.y` which did the trick perfectly.

After that it was just a matter of grabbing that rectangle's lower left corner, making it a Vector3 instead of a Vector2, and passing it back into `ScreenToWorldPoint()`. The only trick *there* was because of the perspective camera, I needed to know *how far away* the line was from the camera originally in order to maintain that same distance (otherwise the line moves up and down the screen faster than the image). For an orthographic camera, this value can be anything.

```
void Update () {
    //the new bits:
    float dist = (Camera.main.transform.position - newListOfPoints[0]).magnitude;
    Rect r = RectTransformToScreenSpace((RectTransform)image.transform);
    Vector3 v3 = new Vector3(r.xMin, r.yMin, dist);

    //more or less original code:
    Vector3 val = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(v3);
    for(int i = 0; i < newListOfPoints.Count; i++) {
        line.SetPosition(i, new Vector3(newListOfPoints[i].x, val.y, newListOfPoints[i].z));
    }
}

//helper function:
public static Rect RectTransformToScreenSpace(RectTransform transform) {
    Vector2 size = Vector2.Scale(transform.rect.size, transform.lossyScale);
    Rect rect = new Rect(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, size.x, size.y);
    rect.x -= (transform.pivot.x * size.x);
    rect.y -= ((1.0f - transform.pivot.y) * size.y);
    return rect;
}
```

<sup>1</sup>And finding *that* post from a generalized search on "how do I get the screen coordinates of a UI object" was not easy. A bunch of other posts came up and had some code, but none of it did what I wanted (including converting screen space coordinates back into world space coordinates of *the UI object* which was stupid easy and not reversibe, thanks [`RectTransformUtility`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransformUtility.html)!)

Comment: I've been looking for a for way to convert UI to world space and don't have time to setup scene to test this. Does this really work?

Comment: @Programmer I tested all of this code in Unity prior to making my answer. It works. :) I'm not set up to record any video though. [The whole class I used](https://pastebin.com/wHHJwVui). [img 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvvSt.png) & [img 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyNwl.png) (I did not bother to set up the line renderer properly). The left edge is center-aligned to the image only because the first point on the line renderer is at X=0 (with the camera centered on the X axis) and the image was also centered to the screen. Asker's code only cared about the Y position.

Comment: Ok good. I will test it with efferent camera and canvas mode settings later on. I think you should also make it a `Vector3` function that converts UI space to world space. I've seen many ignored questions on this subject that reuires converting UI to world postion. I want to use this a duplicate answer to close other old and future questions.

Comment: @Programmer It'd just return the `rect.center` from this function.