# Unity C#: Line renderer from Gameobject (3D) to Canvas (Screen Space - Camera)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a 3D object in my scene and i want to draw a line(LineRenderer) between the 3D object and one Canvas that have rendering mode Screen Space -Camera.

```
    Destination = GameObject.Find("MyCanvas").GetComponent<Canvas>().transform;
    lineRenderer = gameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
    lineRenderer.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Particles/Additive"));
    lineRenderer.SetColors(laserColor,laserColor);
    lineRenderer.SetWidth(initW,finalW);
    lineRenderer.SetVertexCount(2);
    Origin= GameObject.Find("MyObj");
    lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, Origin.position);
    lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, Destination.position);
```

This code works well if the objects are two 3D objects. In my case the line between the 3D object and the Canvas is wrong. The line is going to wrong coordinates from the 3D object.
This is obviuosly a coordinate problem. How can i get the right coordinates from my Canvas? There is some kind of  conversion i have to do?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: The problem is that a ScreenSpace Canvas - as the name already says - exists in the Screen-Space only not in the 3D-World Space. Therefore it is difficult to get a line between both. You can try to get a 3D coordinate though using [Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html) or maybe [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/799616/unity-46-beta-19-how-to-convert-from-world-space-t.html) helps

Comment: I solved this a few months back, let me see if I can find it.

Comment: Hope you can give me some hints Draco ;)

Comment: [Bingo was his name-o](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48133920/how-to-convert-new-canvas-ui-image-position-to-linerenderer-position)

Comment: Thanks Drako for your answer @Draco18s

Comment: No problem! Its a difficult thing to solve and is hard to find the right resources.